# Automatically merge master branch into develop branch

Tags: github, gitlab

I have two branches in my github repository - `master` and `develop` branch. I have a requirement where I need to merge `master` branch into `develop` branch under below conditions:

- Once a PR is merged into master branch then I need to merge master branch back to develop branch automatically.
- Whenever someone adds a commit into master branch directly then I need to merge `master` branch back to `develop` branch automatically.

Is this possible to do by any chance?

**Note:** We already use gitlab internally. Can this be done only via CI/CD pipeline or we can do it directly from the github?

If this can be done only via gitlab then can someone tell me how can I do this via gitlab? I am pretty new to it.

This is our current `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

```
build:
  image: docker.repo.test.data/stuff/something:latest
  variables:
    LEGACY_VERSION: 10000
  before_script:
    - export CI_PIPE_ID=`expr $CI_PIPE_ID + $OLDER_VERSION`
  script:
    - echo "Running step - Run tests"
    - some stuff
    - echo "Running step - Upload to cloud"
    - ls -lrth
    - some other stuff here
```

Comment: Automatically? No.  This would be bad.  Each time, you will need to switch to and pull from master.. switch back to develop and either merge or rebase from master.  You can make a simple script to at least 'try' but "automatically" makes no sense.. what if there is a conflict?

Comment: There will not be any conflicts mostly but yeah atleast I can try with some script and see if it is possible?

Comment: You will still want to trigger it yourself.  It is not smart to have a timer or something else decide when a good time to pull from the server might be.  If you feel differently, you could always use cron/task scheduler (depending on OS) to run your thing automated.. you just have to ask yourself what is this thing supposed to do when it can't and how will it let me know?  Also, git won't let you merge or rebase if files aren't committed..

Comment: I came here looking for the same thing. I can't see why it's bad. At least, Atlassian Bitbucket actually has an option for this, called back-merging

Comment: Just began looking for this solution myself. As long as there are no conflicts, I think it should be the expected behaviour as dev should always have the latest main code (in our case).

In most cases we would merge dev->main so it's already up to date. This article has one github action for it, perhaps it can be ported to gitlab: https://medium.com/@karlstad/create-a-github-actions-workflow-that-auto-merges-the-master-back-to-dev-branch-8b1ebe7009b3